# jquery nth-child as an argument in a function.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have four paragraph elements. I want to toggle the next even element after clicking on an odd  element.

Here's the arrangement.

```
<p>First</p>

<p>Second</p>

<p>Third</p>

<p>Fourth</p>
```

So, if I click on First, I would like Second to be toggled; and if I click on third, I'd like the fourth element to be toggled. I hope it makes sense.

Here's what I have been able to come up with so far.

```
$("p:odd").click(function(){
    $("p:even").toggle("slow");
        });
```

Now, this piece of code toggles ALL the even elements. I just want to toggle n+1, whenever I click an odd paragraph. Does it make sense? Is there a way for that function to take an argument so that after clicking on an odd paragraph, the next (n+1) is toggled? I'm not really sure how to pass an argument or what would be the best way of doing it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside all of your Javascript and jQuery methods, the item that triggers the event is automatically passed to the function as `this`. However, because of the way that variable scope isn't enclosed in Javascript, `this` can change depending on what other functions are called inside. Best practice is to set `this` to another variable immediately.

So, you can adjust your method like this:

```
$("p:odd").click(function(){
    var self = this;

    // I'm doing .next('p') to make your code safer in case there's something between the <p> elements.
    $(self).next('p').toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Nice and detailed answer. Just what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't say this is the best practice. You only really need to do this if you need to access the previous scope's `this` from an inner scope, which isn't that common.

Comment: It's something to get into the habit of, because `this` can easily change what it's referring to. If you forget to do it (or don't know about it), and do come across one of those instances, it could confuse the crap out of you for far too long. http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Comment: @jll90 If you could denote the answer by upvoting and/or marking as answer, that could help other people who come across this answer later and don't read all of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

how about you try `.next()`?   http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
$("p:odd").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle('slow'); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the objects and use `eq` method:

```
var $p    = $('p'), 
    $odd  = $p.filter(':odd'), 
    $even = $p.filter(':even');

$odd.click(function(){
    $even.eq( $odd.index(this) ).toggle('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TLucC/ | http://jsfiddle.net/uNu9y/

Comment: beat you by about 30 seconds :)